# Convert array<String^>^ to std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++

How can I convert a managed `array<String^>^` to `std::vector<std::string>`. The following code doesnt compile and I can't figure out why. Funny enough, if I use an int for example then it works fine. thanks in advance:

```
std::vector<std::string> ConvertToUnManaged(array<String^>^ ar)
{
    using System::IntPtr;
    using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

    std::vector<std::string> vector(ar->Length);
    Marshal::Copy(ar, 0, IntPtr(&vector[0]), ar->Length);

    return vector;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply write a loop to do this?  That Marshall::Copy seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload of `Marshall::Copy` with array of String parameter.

Iterating over the array element and converting one-by-one work.

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

std::vector<std::string> ConvertToUnManaged(array<String^>^ ar)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vector(ar->Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ar->Length; ++i) {
        auto s = ar[i];
        vector[i] = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(s);
    }
    return vector;
}
```

Comment: Thank you NetVipC. If you read my question before, nevermind, I figured it out it was a syntax error